# Testing WCFService1 with Postmen or SoapUI gives 400 Bad Request

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio-2013, soapui, postman

When I make a brand new WCF Service Application named "WcfService1" in Visual Studio 2013 and immediatelly run it, the requests done by WCF Test Client are working flawless. Not a surprise.

When I try to test this same initial application in REST/SOAP clients like Postman or SoapUI, I get a 400 Bad Request error. What should be changed in a REST client like Postman to make the request to the initial VS application work?

Among others I tested these possibilities:

**1. Source code as delivered by initial WCF Service Application**

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        string GetData(int value);
    }
```

For readability I will not paste the source code from the whole project. If you like, you can generate it by creating a new WCF Service Application project in VS.

Below you see how I configured Postman and that it gives 400 Bad Request:

[image]

**2. Raw XML request in Postman as copied from WCF Test Client**

[image]

This variant did not solve the error. Source code untouched, same as above.

**3. Source code extended with WebInvokeAttribute on GetData operation**

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/GetData")]
    string GetData(int value);
```

This addition did not solve the error. All settings in Postman are the same as above; of course with /GetData in the URL.

**4. OperationContractAttribute of GetData operation extended**

```
    [OperationContract(Action = "http://www.jorritsteetskamp.nl/wcfservice1")]
    string GetData(int value);
```

I tried Postman with the SOAPAction header added, but again it resulted in error 400:

[image]

On SO exists several questions about WCF Services and 400 Bad Request errors, but all of them seem application specific and no solution for this case. Since this problem occurs with the initial application as generated by Visual Studio and works in WCF Test Client, I found reason to post this issue.

My question is: What should be changed in a REST client like Postman to make the request to the initial VS application work?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Case 1 : You are posting form-data instead you should be posting SOAP/XML.
- Case 2: You are missing SOAP Action header.
- Case 3 : Request seems ok but you might not have configured WebHttp endpoint.
- Case 4 : Service URL dont need GetData in it.

In order to make it as REST service you need to

1. Annonate service method with WebGet/WebInvoke
2. Configure WebHttp endpoint.
3. Use request from case 3.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, it's just what I needed. For future reference: My solution was to combine case 2 and 4. The Header section of the raw XML from WCF Test Client should be replaced by a real SOAPAction header in the REST client (case 4). And indeed the URL without GetData. In this solution there seems no need to configure WebHttp endpoint as the default configurion by .NET is fine.